# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Archive_Tar' not found in

Tags: magento-1.8

I have this problem with Magento 1.8 Community. There is only one extension installed, nothing custom. This error is shown in the console from Magento Connect and can't figure it out why.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Sebastian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. The file Tar.php was missing in folder ..\downloader\lib\Mage\Archive
Just get it from a clean installation and copy it to this location.
In my case I installed Magento with Softaculou​s, maybe it's your case too.
I hope that will help.

Comment: This worked for me also. The thing is that Magento Connect worked, than started throwing this error. It was some how removed.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue, but for some reason when i ftp back tar.php to the archive directory again it just gets removed after trying to install a extension again. Dont know if it could be some server security reason.